# Extract a uniformly integrable sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

Let $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measurable space. A sequence $\{f_n\}$ of positive measurable functions is said to be uniformly integrable if for any $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ such that if $U$ is a measurable subset with $\mu(U)<\delta$, then $\int_U f_n d\mu<\epsilon$ for any $n$.

Now assume that $\{f_n\}$ is any sequence of positive measurable functions. Under which conditions can we extract a uniformly integrable subsequences from it? Is there any known theorem that ensures that?

Comment: The Dunford-Pettis theorem could be useful: It states that if $(f_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $L^1(\mu)$ with $\mu$ finite,  then $(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable iff it has a weakly convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

Uniform integrability of $(f_n)$ is equivalent to the existence of an increasing convex function $\phi$ mapping $[0,+\infty[$ onto $[0,+\infty[$ such that the sequence integrals of $\phi(|f_n|)$ are bounded.

Hence a criterion for the existence of a uniformly integral subsequence is the existence of a positive increasing convex function $\phi$ mapping $[0,+\infty[$ onto $[0,+\infty[$ such that $\liminf_n \int_X \phi(|f_n|) d\mu < +\infty$.